# Calling a control from form1 in form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to classes one is Form1.cs and one is Form2.cs

in form1.cs i have a tabControl1 and i want to add a tab page to tabcontrol1 (form1) when  i click on a button in FORM2.cs

is this possible

Comment: Form2 will have to have a reference to an instance of Form1.

Comment: @svick Or the other way around and subscribe to the button click even from Form1.

Comment: but not the tabControl1? because I cant seem to do it can u please elaborate

Comment: @svick
Dont ya think that would cause a circular dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Expose `tabControl1` as a public property of `form1`.

Comment: I've done that in the Form1.Designer.cs and i still cant get access to it

Answer (score 0):

Use Events and Delegates, i mean expose some events in Form2, and when Form1 invokes Form2 make Form1 hookup to the exposed events of Form2. When you click some thing in Form2, raise these events. The event handler in Form1 gets invoked/executed and then you can update your UI components there.

Below code should give you a hint:

```
 class MyClass
{
    public delegate void CustomDelegate();
    public event CustomDelegate CustomEvent;

    public void RaiseAnEvent()
    {
        CustomEvent();
    }
}

sealed class Program 
{


    static void Main()
    {

        MyClass ms = new MyClass();

        ms.CustomEvent += new MyClass.CustomDelegate(ms_CustomEvent);
        ms.RaiseAnEvent();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ms_CustomEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event invoked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example to hook up events:

File : Form2.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SO_Suffix
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        //<  The delegate needs to be defined as public in the form that 
        //<  is raising the event...
        public delegate void ButtonClickedOnForm2 (object sender, EventArgs e); 

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
        }

            //<  Capture the click event from the button on Form2, and raise an event
        void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonClicked(this, e);
        }

        public event ButtonClickedOnForm2 ButtonClicked;
    }
}
```

Form1.cs  :  now simply subscribes to the event

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SO_Suffix
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             //<  subscribe to the custom event from form2 and set which function to delegate it to ( form2_ButtonClicked )         
            form2.ButtonClicked += new Form2.ButtonClickedOnForm2(form2_ButtonClicked);
            form2.Show();
        }

        private void form2_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(new Button());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: like on BUTTON2 CLICK not button1 click it should add the control plz n thnx

Comment: now i got the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object:S

Comment: if ( mb==DialogResult . OK ) {
                ButtonClicked ( this , e );
            }

Comment: which object turns out to be null?
you need to have
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
inside your Form1 class...

Comment: AddGroupForm agf = new AddGroupForm();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            agf . ButtonClicked+=new AddGroupForm . ButtonClickedOnForm2 ( form2_ButtonClicked );
            agf . Show ( );
}
 public event ButtonClickedOnForm2 ButtonClicked;
        private void button2_Click ( object sender , EventArgs e ) {
            groupName=textBox1 . Text;

            eData . AddGroup ( textBox1 . Text , richTextBox1 . Text , iconPath );
                ButtonClicked ( this , e );           
        }

Comment: ok, I think you have some items mixed up... I'll edit the example above with full file contents...
Basically your 'public event ButtonClickedOnForm2 ButtonClicked;' is in the wrong location I think...  give me 1 minute to update the answer above...

Comment: basically what is wrong in the code you pasted one comment ago is that the call `ButtonClicked(..)` requires a delegate of the form `public delegate void ButtonClickedOnForm2 (object sender, EventArgs e);` which is not defined hence the gnarly Object Reference not set error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4856/discussion-between-tom-and-suffix)

Answer (score 0):

As I'm leaving Form2 I write a text file containing anything.  (Only the fact that is exists is checked. Nothing is read, but I suppose it's content could be used to update a textbox on Form1.)  This returns Form1 to the screen.  I have a timer in Form1 using a 5 second interval.  The timer checks for the existence of the file written in Form2.  If it exists, it gets deleted and the code which follows the deletion (of the file) updates Form1 using whatever procedures are necessary.